# Mocking a Function with empty parameter list in ZIO Test

Tags: scala, mocking, zio, zio-test

I have the following function I want to mock:

`def deployments(): Task[Seq[Deployment]]`

My envBuilder looks like:

```
ZLayer.fromService(invoke =>
        new processEngineService.Service {
          def deployments(): Task[Seq[Deployment]] =
            invoke(Deployments)
        }
      )
```

How can I set up my expectations for this?

Following the docs (`GetStrLn returns value("42")`) I tried:

```
ProcessEngineMock.Deployments returns value(Seq(deployment))
```

But this gives me:

```
- unsatisfied expectations
  in sequential order
    ..ProcessEngineMock.Deployments with arguments isUnit()
```

How is this done correctly?

Comment: Why do you need to mock is you are using ZIO?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yes I use ZIO and I want to mock this Service because it would require to startup a BPMN Engine.

Comment: From the code it looks like your service is Single Abstract Method. Instead of mocking it you can pretty much build ZLayer using something like `val service: processEngineService.Service = () => Task.pure(Seq(deployment))` and provide that ZLayer to your code.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok - thanks - I just simplified there are more functions - and I want to give zio test mock a try;). But maybe I have to settle with your proposal.